# Angular - Catch error in component

Tags: angular, observable, angular5, rxjs5

i'm making an app in Angular (5), and i'm not very practice with Subject.
I want catch the Observable error in my component, but i can't do.
This is my code

My model:
**example-model.ts**

```
export class ExampleModel { 
    public value: string; 
}
```

My Service:
**example-model-service**

```
@Injectable()
export class ExampleModelService implements OnDestroy{

  destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  private exampleModel$ = new ReplaySubject<ExampleModel>(1);

  constructor() { }

  exampleModelInit(){
    //Observable.from([{'value': 'Hello World'}])
    Observable.create(sub => sub.error('Observable Error'))
      .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      )
      .subscribe((exampleModel: ExampleModel) => {
        this.sendExampleModel(exampleModel);
      },
        err => this._handleError(err));
  }

  private _handleError(err: any) {
    return Observable.throw(err);
  }

  private sendExampleModel(exampleModel: ExampleModel) {
    this.exampleModel$.next(exampleModel);
  }

  public whenExampleModel(): Observable<ExampleModel> {
    this.exampleModelInit();
    return this.exampleModel$.asObservable();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

My Component:
**home-component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public exampleModel$: Observable<ExampleModel>;

  public unsubscribe$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  controls: boolean = false;
  indicators: boolean = false;

  constructor(private exampleModelService$: ExampleModelService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getExampleModel() {
    this.exampleModel$ = this.exampleModelService$.whenExampleModel();

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next(true);
    this.unsubscribe$.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

I want catch my error in `getExampleModel()`, i tried with `.catch` with no result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is you are using a asynchronous method as a normal method that return a value when is executed.

Then, the first change that we need to make is move logic for catch error in this.exampleModelService$.whenExampleModel(); method.

The whenExampleModel() method must return an observable to the consumer for can obtaing asynchronus result. **An asynchronus result is a result that will come in the future but not is available**

Try to change this

```
    @Injectable()
export class ExampleModelService implements OnDestroy{

  destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  private exampleModel$ = new ReplaySubject<ExampleModel>(1);
  private obs : Observable<ExampleModel>;

  constructor() { }

  exampleModelInit(){
    //Observable.from([{'value': 'Hello World'}])
    this.obs = Observable.create(sub => sub.error('Observable Error'))
      .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      );
  }

  private _handleError(err: any) {
    return Observable.throw(err);
  }

  private sendExampleModel(exampleModel: ExampleModel) {
    this.exampleModel$.next(exampleModel);
  }

  public whenExampleModel(): Observable<ExampleModel> {
    this.exampleModelInit();
    return this.obs;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**Component**

whenExampleModel.subscribe(s=>{},e=>{});

Answer (score 0):

Try to return a return this.exampleModel$; rather than return this.exampleModel$.asObservable(); in whenExampleModel service method.

Anyway I like know what is you want make. Could you writte here?

Try this!

```
exampleModelInit(){
//Observable.from([{'value': 'Hello World'}])
Observable.create(sub => sub.error('Observable Error'))
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  )
  .subscribe((exampleModel: ExampleModel) => {
    this.sendExampleModel(exampleModel);
  },
    err => this.sendExampleModel(exampleModel);
```

}

Comment: I want catch when Observable return an error, so in my component i can show an alert or change color of a button

Comment: I want catch error in my Component, so i can show an alert or something else

Comment: Not necessarily, i want catch error, i don't know if there's another method